Geometry Node - Preserving Custom Split Normal Data
I have an object with Sharp_Edges Attribute and Custom Split Normals Data.
I'm instancing it using Geometry Node. But when I try to use the Separate Geometry, Delete Geometry Node, or Realize Instance Node, I'm loosing the Custom Normals.

On the right, original object with Custom split normals, on the left, the objects instanced + Separate nodes or realize instances, as we can see the normals are smoothed out.
I'm using Blender 4.1.1 and I know I could be using the new Smooth By Angle group but in my case it doesn't give the same result.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
